# Validate top level domain from input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

How can I validate a domain name from a url input? I'm currently validating to `www.domain.com`, but need to be able to validate to just `domain.com`. So if a user enters `www` or `http://www.`, it needs to show the error. Also need to disable the content section from showing, unless the validation passes, instead of showing only if the input is not blank.

Currently using:

```
var regExp = new RegExp("^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-     
9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$", "g");
```

but this is validating to `www.domain.com`

jsFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/26hd2r9b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!www\\.|http:\\/\\/www\\.)(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

Simply add `negative lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/7

Comment: I updated my code, but now it's validating if you remove the TLD (.com, .net, etc) after validation: http://jsfiddle.net/26hd2r9b/1/

Comment: It is still allowing domain without `.com, .net`, etc http://jsfiddle.net/26hd2r9b/2/